# How to select an item from a picker and display it on a different page using the button click event in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have been trying to display the selected item of a picker from one page to another when button click event is fired. I am a beginner in Xamarin forms..

I tried to bind the itemsSource of the picker but that does seems to work...

Comment: Use MessagingCenter publish/subscribe.

Comment: Are you navigating from the page with the picker to the next page? If so, then pass the selected value via the page constructor.  It helps a great deal of you post the relevant code so we understand exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

In the xaml:

```
<Picker Title="Items" SelectedIndex="{Binding ItemValue}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

In the code behind:

```
public ItemPage (ItemPageViewModel model)
{
    InitializeComponent ();

    _Model = model;
    BindingContext = _Model;    
}

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new NextPage(_Model));
    await Task.Delay(200);  
}
```

In the ViewModel:

```
private int _ItemValue;
public int ItemValue
{
    get
    {
        return _ItemValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _ItemValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ItemValue));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MessagingCenter to make it. Try the following demo:

In your mainpage.xaml, define a picker and a button:

```
<Picker x:Name="mypicker"
        Title="Select a monkey"
        TitleColor="Red">
        <Picker.ItemsSource>
             <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                 <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
                 <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
             </x:Array>
        </Picker.ItemsSource>
</Picker>
<Button x:Name="mybutton" Clicked="mybutton_Clicked" BackgroundColor="Black"/>
```

In your mainpage.cs, just send a message to the subscriber which will be mentioned later:

```
async void mybutton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var page = new MyPage();  // 
    MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", mypicker.SelectedItem.ToString());  
    await Navigation.PushAsync(page);
}
```

The subscriber is MyPage. It receives the string the publisher (MainPage) send and changes the text of a label:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MainPage, string>(this, "Hi", (sender, values) =>
       {
           this.mylabel.Text = values;
       });          
}
```

For more information, you could refer to [Publish and subscribe to messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter).

Hope my answer could help you.